# In Excel, how can I count the number of times a specific situation occurs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Please see this link: https://ethercalc.org/lh8gegksrlnn

I am looking for a formula to get the daily # of points, as well as the daily # of calls.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The daily # of calls for today:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,TODAY())
```

The daily # of points for today:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,TODAY(),B:B)
```

Comment: That should work great, will try it out tomorrow.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If cell `D1` contained "today's date" (`26-Apr-2018` in your example) then you could use:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A9,D1)
```

...to count the matching values in range `A2:A9`.

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**`COUNTIF`** function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: ...however you are supposed to [look around](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to see if your question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).   (See the [help/on-topic].)

Comment: Can you use the today function with the formula somehow>

Answer (score 0):

To count the daily # of calls for today then use:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,TODAY())
```

and to count the daily # of points for today:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,TODAY(),B:B)
```

This should be all you need.